# UIScrollview+UItextview touch event

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

i am using a scroll view and that scroll view i have UIIMageview and UITextview.My Question is -i want the Touchevent of Textview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think UIScrollView becomes the first responder of touch events, and it doesn't pass the touch events to other view as a default.
So, why don't you create a subclass of the UIScrollView? Then, pass the all touch events which are received by the subclass to the UIIMageview or UITextview like as follows.

```
@implementation SubclassOfScrollView
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self.nextResponder touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
@end
```